# how to make side nav component using angular material 2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

expert.

I want to make `side nav component` using `angular material 2`.

I want to separate `side nav component` and `contents component`.

So, i make two components. side nav and contents.

```
<!--contents.component.html-->
<md-sidenav-container>
  <app-side-nav></app-side-nav>
  <div>Main content</div>
</md-sidenav-container>

<!--side-nav.component.html-->
<md-sidenav mode="side" opened="true">
  <md-list>
    <md-list-item><i class="material-icons" [ngClass]="{'active': activatePath === 'main'}">home</i></md-list-item>
    <md-list-item><i class="material-icons" [ngClass]="{'active': activatePath === 'user'}">person</i></md-list-item>
    <md-list-item><i class="material-icons" [ngClass]="{'active': activatePath === 'gas-setting'}">settings</i></md-list-item>
 </md-list>
</md-sidenav>
```

But, This code is not working well.

Now working

[image]

Expected working

[image]

How do i do for separate two component??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put you sidenev inside container

```
<md-sidenav-container>
<!--side nav component-->
<md-sidenav mode="side" opened="true">
  <md-list>
    <md-list-item><i class="material-icons" [ngClass]="{'active': activatePath === 'main'}">home</i></md-list-item>
    <md-list-item><i class="material-icons" [ngClass]="{'active': activatePath === 'user'}">person</i></md-list-item>
    <md-list-item><i class="material-icons" [ngClass]="{'active': activatePath === 'gas-setting'}">settings</i></md-list-item>
 </md-list>
</md-sidenav>

  <app-side-nav></app-side-nav>
   <div>Main content</div>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

[Here is working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IJSFnPliODUVZQRm5P35?p=preview)

Comment: If i use side nav in another component, How do i do? I think your code can't reusable.

Comment: also i think you should be using router outlet in place of main content all other component would be loaded as child

Comment: I didn't understand your plnkr about how to change component.
But, your comment means I should insert `<router-outlet>` in `<md-sidenav-container>`?

Comment: what you are planning there would be a side nav in your app that will present on all other pages like angular website?

Comment: yes, It's like that. and I change to insert <router-outlet> in <md-sidenav-container>. It's not perfect, but it's solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155475/discussion-between-jitender-and-jong-hyun-kim).